# Find nullable properties through reflection

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to list all properties of an object that are allowed to return nulls?

```
val cls = javaClass<T>().kotlin

for(property in cls.properties) {
    if(property.accessible) {
        //Is it nullable?

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to find @Nullable annotations?

Comment: @D3xter this won't work because the Nullable annotation used by Kotlin is not retained at runtime.

Comment: This is now currently possible using Kotlin reflection since M13 release

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The API you're looking for was introduced in latest Kotlin builds (0.13.213+). You can now take the type of a property and find out if it was marked as nullable in the source code:

```
val property = ...
if (property.returnType.isMarkedNullable) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Without returnType the API was a little incomplete.